Add a role to Keycloaks custom user storage
I have implemented this example for user storage in JPA in Keycloak.
But I can not figure out how to add a group and role information to the user so it is visible in the JWT token. I guess it has to be set into this UserAdapter or the 'UserEntity entity' object. How exactly to set group info?
I tried to add
  protected List<GroupModel> groups = new ArrayList<>();
  protected List<RoleModel> roles = new ArrayList<>();

to UserAdapter class but it does not reflect in the JWT token content.
